# Did the mothership lazers zap the favourite and ignored tags?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

**Update**

My Favorites dialogue area has been missing since the ME3 contest, more specifically the removal/readdition of the mothership lazers.

I have since found where it went.  I suppose it figured if it ducked down below the questions it would be out of range of the lazers.

[image: Community Bulletin In Hiding!]

This is happening under Win7 64 bit, Google Chrome 18.1025.162

I have a dual monitor configuration the primary display is 1366x768 landscape the second is 1024x1280 portrait, desktop extended across both.  The error occurs regardless of which monitor the web page is displayed on and is not happening on any other se site, including meta.g.se.

Comment: status-norepro, it's there on mine...

Comment: Mine most certainly do appear. Consider listing OS and browser used.

Comment: norepro as well, thee is a lot more than tags on the right hand side and your missing everything. Try IE no addons, Firefox safemode etc etc to see if it helps.

Comment: @oak Done. (non trivial check done!)

Comment: @Resorath IE works fine, everything appears.

Comment: they work for me too, Win 7 64 Chrome latest beta release

Comment: Still can't reproduce. Win 7 64 bit, 17.0.963.83 m.

Comment: Same config at home, not happening.  I'll have to try clearing my cache and see if that does it.

Comment: 17.0.963.83 (Official Build 127885) m win 7 64bit, favorite tags still there

Comment: Hey thanks! I've been trying not to spoiler ME3, and didn't know I could hide tags!

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce on your original machine?

Comment: @JarrodDixon I haven't ... clearing my cache did nothing.  It also is not happening on any other SE site, only gaming. *sigh*  I love no-repro so much as a developer ... I'm sure everyone else is enjoying it just as much

Comment: I'm enjoying tagging this as [status-norepro], muhaha! :)  If you see this happening again, let us know and maybe inspect the page's elements to see if `div#interesting-tags` is present.

Comment: @Stephen if you disable all addons in Chrome does it fix it?

Comment: Yeah, I would try reproducing the issue from an incognito session, which usually has all addons disabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens in Firefox and Chrome for me if I decrease the zoom level (zoom out). I posted this bug over in meta SO ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126885/153767)). You can reproduce this by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to restore).

Try zooming IN (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>) to see if that helps. I'm not sure if Marc Gravell is still working on this bug.

Comment: Ah HA!  This is it!  That worked